# Cursor theme XFCE

Tags: themes, xubuntu, xfce, cursor

This is a weird bug I'm experiencing.  Basically when I try to apply a cursor theme, it only shows up in my firefox (the theme, that is).  Whenever I'm on the desktop for example, it goes back to my stock theme.

I'm running Xubuntu 12.10 64-bit, with Nvidia Proprietary drivers activated.